# Source code auditing tool

Tags: project-management, programming, source-code, code-review

Often I need to look at source code of external teams and I wonder if there is a tool where I can preform a code review and write comments on top of the files (not directly in the code, similar to comments in Google docs), and in the end output a report for that review?

I have seen [reviewboard.org](https://www.reviewboard.org), but I'm looking for a tool which is much simple than that. In addition, most code review tools that I have seen are based on a VCS commits and pull requests, while I'm getting the code as is without access to any VCS.

In general code review/audit tools that I have seen assume that the one who is doing the review is part of the team and part of the development lifecycle (a fair assumption), but in my scenario it's not the case - it's more as a retrospective code review.